# Why doesn't the "display more" link work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my [online resume](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/carlmanaster), the "display more" links below my first two jobs and below my first three books do not work.

Why not?

What can I do to make them work?

Comment: It seems there is JavaScript code that is not kicking in.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be IE-only. We’ll have a fix up in just a few…

Comment: @MattSherman It happens to me too, and I am not using Internet Explorer, if not in the case Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS X is really Internet Explorer undercover. `:-)`

Comment: @Matt I'm on Firefox 3.6.24 on Mac OS 10.4.11.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Would you try it again?

Comment: This is fixed.  Thanks!  Can you explain what was wrong?  (just curious)

Comment: We had a dependency on underscore.js which I mistakenly removed.